# Responsive Design Breaking on Staging Site

Tags: wordpress, responsive

I'm setting up a staging site to test changes before putting them live, but the stage site's responsive design isn't working.

I deactivated all my plugins, but the responsive design still doesn't work on stage site.

I created a new local copy of the original site and added the plugins one by one and the responsive design worked, so the plugins aren't breaking it.

I believe I've narrowed down the issues to a problem that occurs in the enqueue code in functions.php located in the child-theme directory

```
function add_theme_scripts() {

    $parent_style = 'Karma'; // This is 'twentyfifteen-style' for the Twenty Fifteen theme.

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'Karma-child',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);

   if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
     wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
   }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_theme_scripts' );
```

Here's the live site:  www.alliancechemical.com

Here's the stage site:  www.alliancechemical.com/staging

I expect that when the screen resolution gets smaller into mobile territory then the breakpoint media query will take effect and make the css adjustments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your live site your theme css files are version 4.7.15 and on your staging 5.2.4 and they change the order the of the selectors.

Css on #main on staging:

```
#main.tt-slider-karma-custom-jquery-2 {
    margin-top: -189px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1023px)
#main.tt-slider-karma-custom-jquery-2 {
    margin-top: -157px; //Disabled
}
```

Css on #main on live:

```
#main.tt-slider-karma-custom-jquery-2 {
    margin-top: -157px; 
}
#main.tt-slider-karma-custom-jquery-2 {
    margin-top: -189px; //Disabled
}
```

The solution is to deregister the mobile css and then enqueue it again with the theme css as a dependency.

Comment: I don't think the issue is the different versions of the style.css because I tested this on a local copy of live site. Duplicated it and updated the theme but I didn't create a child theme and enqueue it.  The responsive design worked just fine.

Comment: Good chance your child theme is loading them in a different order then. I promise you the order issue is breaking the responsive.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly the order my css files are loaded determines which rules take precedence?

Comment: Correct. Assuming the selectors are the same (they are, see my answer), the 2nd assignment will overwrite the first.

Comment: Ah it seems to be ignoring my _mobile.css file that's responsible for the theme's responsive css and just using style.css.  However, under the sources I see the _mobile.css

Comment: I can see under the network that the style.css file is loaded 1st, then below it _mobile.css.  Wouldn't that mean that _mobile.css should take precedence, since it was loaded last?

Comment: If you add the mobile styles to the bottom of the style.css file you can avoid all of this, and it reduces the number of scripts loaded by 1. I'll check on the order in a sec.

Comment: If I paste the contents of _mobile.css to the bottom of style.css that fixes the issue.  However, I don't want to make changes to the Theme's core files in case there's an issue when I update.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201973/discussion-between-daniel-taki-and-kgreene).